# Upgrade SonarQube from 5.3 to 5.6 caused PMD Absent Code attribute in javax/ws/rs/core/Application

Tags: java, sonarqube, pmd, sonarqube-scan

We are doing a test upgrade from SonarQube 5.3 to SonarQube 5.6.6. We upgraded the PMD plugin to 2.6. During a test build I get this error:

```
15-Aug-2017 12:23:39    [INFO] Sensor PmdSensor
15-Aug-2017 12:23:39    [INFO] Execute PMD 5.4.2...
15-Aug-2017 12:23:39    [INFO] Java version: 1.8
15-Aug-2017 12:23:39    [INFO] PMD configuration: /localdisk/home/bambooagent/agent1/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/myproj/TaskDashboard-war/target/sonar/pmd.xml
15-Aug-2017 12:23:39    Aug 15, 2017 12:23:39 PM net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.typeresolution.ClassTypeResolver visit
15-Aug-2017 12:23:39    WARNING: Could not find class com.myco.TaskDashboard.SampleClientApplication, due to: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/ws/rs/core/Application
15-Aug-2017 12:23:39    [INFO] Execute PMD 5.4.2 done: 137 ms
```

and

```
15-Aug-2017 12:23:41    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.2:sonar (default-cli) on project main: Execution default-cli of goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.2:sonar failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.2:sonar: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/ws/rs/core/Response$Status
15-Aug-2017 12:23:41    [ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
15-Aug-2017 12:23:41    [ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.2
15-Aug-2017 12:23:41    [ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
15-Aug-2017 12:23:41    [ERROR] urls[0] = file:/localdisk/home/bambooagent/agent1/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/mydir/maven_repo/local/org/sonarsource/scanner/maven/sonar-maven-plugin/3.0.2/sonar-maven-plugin-3.0.2.jar
```

I tried on my local machine with sonar-maven-plugin 3.3.0.603 and got the same thing.

Why does changing the SQ version or PMD plugin version cause compile problems? What version of the sonar-maven-plugin should I use with SQ5.6.6?

How do I fix this problem? (Please don't suggest eliminating PMD as we currently use over 80 PMD rules and I can't randomly change rules in the middle of a release.)

Comment: That's a known bug: https://github.com/pmd/pmd/issues/328 It will be fixed for the next release (6.0.0). In the meantime, other than changing dependencies to make sure the PMD analysis can find a valid class there is little you can do. More details on the issue.

Comment: @Johnco Thanks. Annoying that the PMD operation changed just upgrading my Sonar plugin from PMD 2.5 to 2.6. The issue makes it sound like an enhancement needed, but the fact that it's new on upgrade sounds like a bug. Fixing it in 6.0 also means that I won't get it from SonarQube until going to their 6.0 well in the future. I'll have to sonar.skip this module for now.

Comment: the Sonar plugin is a very thin wrapper around PMD, so the whole point of updating is to get an updated version of PMD. This means new rules, fixes and improvements most of the time, but as with any upgrade, you may get new issues too. *This one is very definitely a bug, and the issue is labeled as such.* The referenced class **is indeed invalid**, but PMD shouldn't crash. Having invalid classes in the classpath was, understandably, never a test scenario when developing the first stage of improved type resolution. Providing your feedback directly to PMD's team helps making it better!